# Exact same request does not work on another computer on same network

Tags: python, server, python-requests

I have the following python code to send a get request to a particular website. Without the headers, the request is dropped and Cloudflare returns an anti-bot message.

It works on my PC. However, on my laptop, with the exact same code and headers, it does not work. Both are connected to the same router and both use the same version of requests. Both computers have the same IP address publically.

```
import requests

headers = {
    
    "Host": "highschooltutors.com.au",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": '"Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"',
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "Windows",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get('https://highschooltutors.com.au/', headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

This is the successful response I get on my PC (truncated for brevity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>High School tutors for all subjects near you – HighSchoolTutors.com.au</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Find great high school tutors for the subjects and years you need - near you, your school or online." />
```

This is the unsuccessful response I get on my laptop (truncated for brevity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body class="no-js"><div class="main-wrapper" role="main"><div class="main-content"><noscript><div id="challenge-error-title"><div class="h2"><span class="icon-wrapper"><div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div></span><span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span></div></div></noscript></div></div>
```

I don't know what the difference between these requests are! Shouldn't they be identical?

Comment: Does the page use JScript? Have you got a look to requests-html?

Comment: Which python version are you running on each machine?

Comment: @Stickleback they're the same as well sadly